# Waiting for ... url cookie chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, cookies

Is it possible to hide the origin cookie url loading with another url or without making anything appear?

```
<iframe src="https://www.example.com/"></iframe>
```

I do not want it to be possible to see the writing: "waiting for www.example..."

Comment: No, you cannot do that because it's done by the browser, not by your page. You would need to re-programm the browser to do that.

Comment: So it's not even possible to load the browser other than that?

Comment: No, there's nothing we can do about that.